# A way to transfer a state of a component to the diagram

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I searched but I don't know if it is possible to transfer my state of a components whos is in client/src/components to my graphql diagram schema/.

I explain myself in my diagram I make an axios API request to have the data to which I make new ObjectGraphQl.

And in this axios request I have a date which for the moment is hard I would like in my component to have an input which updates the state and this state send it in the diagram so that my date is this state, I know not if it's clear enough.

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    matchs: {
      type: new GraphQLList(NumGamesType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            `http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/20200209/scoreboard.json`
          )
          .then(response => response.data.games);
      }
    },
    match: {
      type: detailType,
      args: {
        gameId: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            `http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/20200209/${
            args.gameId
            }_boxscore.json`
          )
          .then(response => response.data);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And follow all my GraphQlObjectype ex:

```
const NumGamesType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Matchs",
  fields: () => ({
    gameId: { type: GraphQLString },
    vTeam: { type: vTeamType },
    hTeam: { type: hTeamType }
  })
});
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if I understood correctly you want to have a component with an `input` that sets the value of the `input` to `state`. Then you want to send this state using a post request to the GraphQL so that it is stored there?

You need to create an `<input />` field, a `<button />` to handle clicks, and a handle click function that sends this.state.date to the GraphQL.

This function will set the state whenever you type something in the input field, just pass this to the onChange parameter of a input field

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({ date: e.target.value });
 }
```

This function will call axios to send data to GraphQL, but you need to configure it properly

```
  handleClick = () => {
      // axios.post(your urls and configuration and parameter of this.state.date)
  }
```

Comment: Yes in the idea it is that but my state will just come to change the Axios address for my Api request for the moment this is :  ` const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    matchs: {
      type: new GraphQLList(NumGamesType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            `http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/20200209/scoreboard.json`
          )
          .then(response => response.data.games);
      }
    },` and after i want change the date 20200209 
by the date that I entered in the input

Comment: Then you need to call this url instead:    `http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/${this.state.date}/scoreboard.json`

Comment: It doesn' work because i'm in the serverside i think i'm not in client folder `console.log(this.state.date);
[0]                        ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`

Comment: So the place where you have your input isnt connected to the place where you make your API call? That makes things a bit harder. You need to be able to pass the data in this.state.date to the place where you call the api, if you call the api from the server side, then you need to send a request to the server side with the data, then use it to send it the api request further

Comment: Yes here it is exactly that but there I am blocked as to how to do that to be able to communicate my state.date to my side server and make my request axios

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you would have the api call on the server side, normally the client side would be making the requests to the serverside, not having a client communicate with a server that communicates with another server. This makes it three steps and not one.